# Toggling Multiple Icon Colors onClick with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a sidebar with icons that act in a similar manner to this http://piccsy.com/.

Right now I can make the background of each list element and the font-color to toggle appropriately, but I want to toggle the color of each icon as well.

```
$( function() {
  $('li').click( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("green_select");
    $('span', this).toggleClass("white_letters");


    $('.category_icon',this).toggle(function () {

        });
    });
});
```

I'm stuck on the last line. Right now the toggle shows/hides each icon. I'm not sure if I need to have the toggle pull a different url from my css or if there is another way to go about changing the color.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The whole point of `toggle()` is to ["Display or hide the matched elements."](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). It sounds like it's doing exactly what it is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of an element:

```
$selection.css('color', 'newColor')
```

where `$selection` is the matched set of elements you wish to change, and `newColor` is a CSS color value such as `red` or `#333`.